# CakePHP3 - Reverse (delete) generated (baked) controller

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-bake

I generated (baked) controller via terminal command:

`bin/cake bake.bake controller [controller_name]`

Is there a command to reverse it? To delete generated controller?

Comment: can you not just delete the file? else `rm src/controller/[controller_name]`

Comment: @mcgowan.b yeah, that is not the only file that was generated.

Comment: just delete the files generated or if you have git installed, revert it via git?

Comment: Yeah all the workarounds, in that case it is way more practical to write my own shell script for generating and managing files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CakePHP does not have reverse generator.

When deleting files with `rm -rf` or by hand, you should note that new files are not only generated inside Controller directory. You should also track other files in test and template directories.

Possible workaround for this is to use a real framework like Ruby On Rails or write your own shell scripts for generating or deleting.

Comment: Had a nice article on how to remove the baked things from bake pan... but forgot to link